# Titanfall 2 regenerating after getting the starter pack. Will i still have the stuff

Tags: titanfall-2

The jump starter pack will give you pilot tacticals and titans. Will I still have those things when I regenerate

Answer (score -1):

I do not know about TF2 in particular, but it would be illogical that you would lose something bought will real money when you reset your rank.

Also, if i remember right, in Call of Duty Modern Warfare 2 when you presiged (same process, its the same devs) you would lose gun attachments and stuff, but for everything that is visual you would keep.